# In Elasticsearch, how to use a range query on a text field?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, querydsl

There is a 'remark' field in Elasticsearch index that contains various remarks along with the date when that remark was given.  For example:

```
remark
------
14/02/2023 To be updated ; 15/02/2023 Further action is needed ; 16/02/2023 Looks good
```

Due to some implementation specific reasons, I can't split date as a separate field.  I need to query all the records that match a given date range in 'remark' field.  For example: Retrieve all the records that are in the date range 15/02/2023 and 16/02/2023.

I have written the following query in Elasticsearch:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
"query"
  : {
    "bool"
    : {
        "must"
        : [
            {
                "range"
                : {
                    "remark"
                    : {
                        "gte" : "2023-02-15",
                        "lte" : "2023-02-16"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  },
  "highlight"
  : {
    "fields"
    : {
        "content"
        : {
            "type"                : "unified",
            "fragment_size"       : 150,
            "number_of_fragments" : 3,
            "pre_tags"            : [""],
            "post_tags"           : [""]
        }
    }
  },
  "size"
  : 1000
}
```

The above query doesn't work since the field 'remark' is not of type datetime.  Is there any workaround to this issue?

Comment: Can you update the documents after the fact in order to add those dates into another field that you can query?

Comment: No, it isn't allowed, change in structure is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use **text** or **keyword** field type with `range` query but it's an expensive query, so it's disabled by default.

> **Using the range query with text and keyword fields**
>
> Range queries on text or keyword fields will not be executed if
> search.allow_expensive_queries is set to false.

I won't recommend you to enable it but if you want you can use:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient": {
    "search.allow_expensive_queries": "true"
  }
}
```

> After you update the cluster settings your query will work.

**Recommendation:
add a new field:**

```
PUT index_name/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "remark_date": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

and update the data, the update by query will add a new field and value for each document.

```
POST index_name/_update_by_query?wait_for_completion=false
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-text-and-keyword